# WITH Clause with union all - Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Can anyone explain the following query?

With clause query alias `recursiveBOM` is being used inside query? Is there anything with UNION ALL?

```
 WITH recursiveBOM
    (assembly_id, assembly_name, parent_assembly) AS
 (SELECT parent.assembly_id,
         parent.assembly_name,
         parent.parent_assembly
 FROM bill_of_materials parent
 WHERE parent.assembly_id=100
 UNION ALL
 SELECT child.assembly_id,
        child.assembly_name,
        child.parent_assembly
 FROM recursiveBOM parent, bill_of_materials child
 WHERE child.parent_assembly = parent.assembly_id)
 SELECT assembly_id, parent_assembly, assembly_name
 FROM recursiveBOM;
```

Comment: your question is not very much clear are you want to know WITH AS clause works?? or you want to know about UNION ALL

Comment: Purpose of using With alias(recursiveBOM ) inside query itself.!!

Comment: Conceder the alias as a virtual table think that you are select all data in the alias virtually in memory. now think what you do normally in selecting data from a table u use table name. so in this case the table is the alias. Hope it clarify your query.

Comment: This is how a recursive common table expression is written - a self join to the CTE itself. See the manual for details https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH recursiveBOM
 AS
 (
 SELECT parent.assembly_id,
         parent.assembly_name,
         parent.parent_assembly
 FROM bill_of_materials parent
 WHERE parent.assembly_id=100
 )
 recursiveBOM2 as
 (
 SELECT child.assembly_id,
        child.assembly_name,
        child.parent_assembly
 FROM   bill_of_materials child
  )
SELECT recursiveBOm.assembly_id, recursiveBOm.parent_assembly, recursiveBOm.assembly_name
 FROM recursiveBOm
 UNION ALL
 SELECT recursiveBOM2.assembly_id, recursiveBOM2.parent_assembly, recursiveBOM2.assembly_name
 FROM recursiveBOm, recursiveBOm2
 WHERE recursiveBOm.assembly_id = recursiveBOM2.parent_assembly
;
```

Comment: Analyze and order the query, the result can only be seen with the database. it works with similar options that I've worked